# why am i getting error message on MainActivity Java?

Tags: android

I always get an error warning anytime i want to set find view by id

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
View pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pdfView.**fromAsset**("").load();
}
```

The error comes from "fromAsset." It always highlighted in red.
Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Post the content of the `activity_main`

Comment: You are calling findViewById before your onCreate, it will not work in general as the content was not yet set (correct me if I'm wrong). I'm assuming the fromAsset is in red because it's telling you that you'll get NPE (null pointer exception) as no value can be given to pdfView as mentioned, due to calling findViewByID prior to calling setContentView

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize View inside onCreate() Method.

```
View pdfView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    pdfView.**fromAsset**("").load();
}
```